# Can you get the current record number in Power Query without adding an index column first?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, indices

Obviously, you can just add an index column starting from zero and refer to it when you need to know what record you are on.

This is particularly helpful when you want to refer to the next or previous record.

My question is, can I get the record number without making an index column first?

Obviously, Power Query is aware of what record it is on. Where does it hide this information and how can I most directly access it?

I would like to be able to use such a feature when iterating with each.

Something like this:

```
each _.recordnumber
```

Again, I know this can be done adding an index. But it just irks me to do so.

Comment: Add the index column and move on. :)

Comment: I know. I know. But aren't you just driven crazy when you have to do a computers work for it? Like, I know you know! You have to! Just tell me what it is...aaaargh.

Comment: In general, writing iterative logic is a bad idea when working with columnar data. You need to sometimes but often there's a better way. I'm curious what you are trying to do in particular.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/generic-function-for-interpolating-missing-values-in-power-query

Comment: @AlexisOlson Did you check out the above link? Do you consider this a situation where iterative logic is warranted?

Comment: There are absolutely cases where it's warranted. That's why I was curious.